# can asset catalogs eliminate the need for iOS device resource extensions in sprite sheets?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios7, xcode5, texturepacker, xcasset

I have been using texture packer for most of my image resources. Recently I read about asset catalogs that eliminate the need to specify iOS device extensions needed for resources. can asset catalogs eliminate the need for iOS device resource extensions in sprite sheets? if yes, how? Also, can asset catalogs work with apps that run on older versions of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless cocos2d-iphone gets an update to support asset catalogs: no.

FWIW not even Sprite Kit currently supports asset catalogs, though it's said to be on the roadmap.

Asset catalogs work on apps built for iOS 7, which means if you're still targeting iOS 6 or earlier you couldn't use them.

Comment: Cocos2d aside, Asset Catalogs DO work with iOS 6. I have used them in one of my apps. For reference, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031406/is-xcode-5-asset-catalog-backwards-compatible-with-pre-ios-7).