# How to make Asset Icons work for iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5, icons

I have created a new iPad project in XCode 5.01.
The deployment target is set to 5.1.1 (to support the old iPad-1).

I am using the *asset catalog* (se picture below). But when i run the app on my iPad-1, the icon becomes blank (and glossy).

In some related questions the answer is to skip the *asset catalog* and instead make a patch to the *info.plist* file. **Question:** Can I use the XCode's Asset Catalog feature if I like to support iOS-5 ?

[image]

Comment: Refer following URL that might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031406/is-xcode-5-asset-catalog-backwards-compatible-with-pre-ios-7